# E(XZ) where X and Z are dependent with X~Bin(m, p) and Z~Bin(n+m,p)

Tags: probability, expected-value, binomial-distribution

We have 2 racks with holding holes. Rack 1 holds red balls and  rack 2 holds white balls. Each rack has holes along its length where a ball can be present. Along both racks each hole is either empty with probability $1-p$ or holds 1 ball with $p \in (0,1)$ independently. Integers m and n are fixed and are smaller than number of holes in each rack. Balls contained within first m holes in rack 1 and first n holes in rack 2 are placed in an urn. Let X be the number of red balls in urn and Y be number of white balls in urn and Z be total number of balls in urn.

I know X~Bin(m,p) and Y~Bin(n,p) and Z=X+Y~Bin(m+n,p).

How do I find E(XZ)?

Comment: To get started, just write it as $E[X^2+XY]$...then use linearity of expectation and...

Comment: So $E(X^2 + XY) = E(X^2) + E(XY)$ and since X and Y are independent we have $= (np)^2 +np(1-p) +E(X)E(Y) = (mp)^2 +mp(1-p) + mp*np$ Where do i go from there?

Comment: I don't understand.  You have computed the expectation.  What more do you want?

Comment: Oh i see. $XZ =X(X+Y) =$ $X^2 +XY$ right.

Comment: I mean , you can simplify the algebra a bit, if you are so inclined.  Write it as $Ap+Bp^2$ for suitable $A,B$.